# Find all beans with custom annotation and create resolver from this beans

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyHandler {
    MyType type();
}
```

And I have 3 classes:

```
@MyHandler(type = MyType.TYPE1)
@Component
public class MyFirstHandler implements MyHandler {

    public MyResponse test() {
        return new MyResponse("first");
    }

}

@MyHandler(type = MyType.TYPE2)
@Component
public class MySecondHandler implements MyHandler {

    public MyResponse test() {
        return new MyResponse("second");
    }

}

@MyHandler(type = MyType.TYPE3)
@Component
public class MyLastHandler implements MyHandler {

    public MyResponse test() {
        return new MyResponse("last");
    }

}
```

I need find all beans with `@MyHandler` annotations and create `resolver` from this beans. After that I need this locic:

```
MyHandler  handler  = resolver.getHandler(MyType.TYPE3)
```

How can I do it with spring boot?

Comment: Why? Just create a resolver that delegates to the `ApplicationContext` and use the `getBeansWithAnnotation` method to retrieve the correct one(s).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a component autowiring all beans of the `MyHandler` type, which then filters upon query:

```
@Component
public class HandlerResolver {
    @Autowired List<MyHandler> handlers;

    public MyHandler getHander(MyType type) {
        handlers.stream()
            .filter(h -> hasAnnotation(type))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(new IllegalArgumentException("no handler found"));
    }

    private boolean hasAnnotation(MyHandler h, MyType type) {
        MyHandlerAnnotation an = h.class.getAnnotation(MyHandlerAnnotation.class);
        return an != null && an.type() == type);
    }
}
```